# Following an update, iPhone now lists my gmail account as inactive

Tags: iphone, gmail, accounts

A message appeared on my iPhone this morning but went before I could read it properly. Something about an application update I think, not sure. Now I see under Accounts that my gmail account is listed as inactive.

Before this, I had calendar and contacts sync enabled, and used Inbox by Gmail for mail. Now calendar and contacts syncing are toggled off, and the account is not visible in Inbox by Gmail.

I have checked App Store updates, but all I can see is that Inbox by Gmail was recently updated, with a date 6 days ago.

I don't know:

- if that has anything to do with it
- if the date refers to when the update was released or when it was installed
- why the update should be responsible for making the gmail account inactive
- or if it wasn't, what was.

And I don't know how to find the notification message that disappeared. It's not in the notifications center.

Any ideas gratefully received :-)

Comment: Have you tried signing out and in of your google account under in “accounts” in settings on your iPhone? I’m not sure that inbox is tied to that. Maybe reinstall the app and try signing in again?

Comment: Thanks JBallin. I'm pretty sure we can reactivate it again, but I was really keen to understand 'what went wrong', so to speak, in case there was something I should reconfigure, or indeed in case there was any kind of hacking shenanigans going on. It would help to know what the original message said, but I can find no way to find it if indeed that's possible.